# Prove that for any fixed non-negative random variable X with finite mean, $ \lim_{x\to ∞}\frac{xP(X≥x)}{E[X]}\ = 0 $

Tags: probability

Prove that for any fixed non-negative random variable X with finite mean,

$$ \lim_{x\to ∞}\frac{xP(X≥x)}{E[X]}\ = 0$$

I think I should try to use Markov's Inequality but I am unsure how to start it.

Comment: Where is that from? Also, the $\mathbb{E}[X]$ in the denominator serves no purpose: since by assumption the expectation is finite, the numerator goes to 0 iff the whole fraction goes to 0.

Comment: I believe the problem included the [X] as a hint to use Markov's Inequality. I had the same thoughts about its relevance

Answer (score 4):

First of all, note that your claim is eqivalent to $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x \mathbb{P}(X \geq x) = 0. \tag{1}$$ To prove $(1)$ use that $$x \mathbb{P}(X \geq x) = \int_{\{X \geq x\}} x \, d\mathbb{P} \leq \int_{\{X \geq x\}} X \, d\mathbb{P}$$ and apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am a bit unsure how you would use the dominated convergence theorem in this situation.

Comment: @qwefgh Surely you can use the dominated convergence theorem to show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\{X \geq n\}} X \, d\mathbb{P}=0.$$ Now use the monotonicty of the integral to prove $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{\{X \geq x\}} X \, d\mathbb{P}=0.$$

Comment: Still a little uncertain. Can we use it due to the fact that we have a finite mean?

Comment: @qwefgh For the dominated convergence theorem you need a dominating function which is integrable. What would be a good choice for such a dominating function for our sequence $u_n := 1_{\{X \geq n\}} X$....?